# Spring remember-me with custom authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I want to implement remember me services for my application. The main problem I am facing is I am using a custom authentication provider . which uses a third party application for authentication. I dont have direct access to their DB.

I checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331784/spring-security-remember-me-with-custom-authentication-provider) and It tells implementation of UserDetailService is Mandatory for userauthenticxation service. Unfortunately in my case I cant do this.

I checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734484/spring-security-config-error-while-server-startup) as well and it says you may also implement a `customRememberMeServices` . But I am not sure how this is done. It just passes a request and a response which doesn't have the credentials.

With the limited understanding I have; spring stores userName and password in the token

```
 base64(username + ":" + expirationTime + ":" +
         md5Hex(username + ":" + expirationTime + ":" password + ":" + key))

username:          As identifiable to the UserDetailsService
password:          That matches the one in the retrieved UserDetails
expirationTime:    The date and time when the remember-me token expires,
                   expressed in milliseconds
key:               A private key to prevent modification of the remember-me token
```

Is there a way I can retrieve password from this token ? if not how else I can achieve the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The token is a one-way hash. The whole point is that the password is used to create the token and it can later be verified using the same data when the user connects again. If you can't read the password from the database then you can't use this method directly. You could create a fake random password for each user and store it in a database which you do have access to, and implement a `UserDetailsService` which loads that instead.

Alternatively, you can use the alternative ["persistent token"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#remember-me-persistent-token) implementation, which stores the actual token in the database, rather than rebuilding it from unique user data.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. But <PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices> requires a user details sevice. The only difference being the storage of the token . rt ?.. Say I am going to re-implement the rememeberme service's autoLogin method, is it possible for me to retrieve the username from the request ?

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use the fake password solution as the third party application also get initialized as part of login, so apart from just authentication some context initialization is also done in the third party application and can be done only with the original password